# case sensitve query returns string instead of list

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, case-sensitive, identifier

I have an issue executing a query using python's pgdb using multiple case sensitive columns.  The results of most queries return a python list, but if I issue a query against a table specifying multiple case sensitive columns the result is a `string`.

For example I have a table in a PostgreSQL database with 3 case-sensitve `boolean` columns named:

```
(colA, colB, debug)
```

If I'm interested in selecting more than one column I receive a raw `string` result from the query:

```
query = 'SELECT ("colA", debug) FROM my_table;"
```

or

```
query = 'SELECT ("colA", "colB") FROM my_table;"
```

the query will return:

```
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.fetchone()
['(f,f)']
```

Issuing the following query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM my_table;"
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.fetchone()
```

results in the expected python list:

```
[False, False, False]
```

and if I specify one column in quotes the result is expected:

```
query = 'SELECT ("colA") FROM my_table;'
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.fetchone()
[False]
```

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction to understand why I receive a raw `string` when selecting multiple case-sensitve columns.  I could issue multiple queries to solve my problem, or just `SELECT *` but to maintain robust code and protect myself against future changes to the table, I'd prefer to specify my columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enclose multiple coumns in parentheses you form an ad-hoc row-type, resulting in a single value returned.

```
SELECT ("colA", "colB") FROM my_table;
```

Drop the parens to get individual columns:

```
SELECT "colA", "colB" FROM my_table;
```

If in doubt about double-quoting, read the [chapter about identifiers in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). My standing advice is to use legal, lower-case identifiers only in PostgreSQL.